# How this ToArray() implementation more optimized?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, optimization

I just take a look at our code base's history and found a check-in that change from this:

```
    public virtual T[] ToArray()
    {
        List<T> list = new List<T>();
        foreach (object item in List)
        {
            list.Add((T)item);
        }

        return list.ToArray();
    }
```

to this:

```
    public virtual T[] ToArray()
    {
        T[] result = new T[List.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < List.Count; ++i)
        {
            result[i] = (T)List[i];
        }

        return result;
    }
```

with the comment: Optimized ToArray implementation to avoid creating multiple data structures in the process.

I wonder myself why there's an optimization here. `for()` may be faster than `foreach()`, but where's the "creating multiple data structures"?

P/S: The guy who wrote this is on vacation now

Comment: The biggest optimization I see is the avoidance to use list and just simply stick with array through out the process

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the original code, you create a `List<T>` - without specifying a capacity, so it could involve copying the internal array several times - and then you call `ToArray` on the `List<T>`, resulting in a copy.

The newer version doesn't do that. It creates one array, and copies the original list into it.

Admittedly just using LINQ's `ToArray` method would be simpler and quite possibly even more efficient, and it's not clear why this is a virtual method to start with, but...

Answer (score 3):

The first implementation creates a middle-man extra List object; it is simply one more thing for the GC to clean up.  This optimization will almost assuredly not be noticeable, unless this routine is hit at fiendishly high levels.

Otherwise, it has nothing to do with whether it uses `foreach` or `for`.  That choice was motivated largely by the rule that a list can't be modifed while it is being enumerated.

Comment: It would be awkward to use `foreach` while building an array like this, because you'd still need to keep the index to know where to *write* to the array.

Answer (score 0):

For even faster performance for converting a List to an Array, HPCsharp nuget package implements a parallel (multi-core) version of List.ToArray():

```
public virtual T[] ToArray()
{
    return List.ToArrayPar();
}
```

This method shouldn't be necessary, but just use List.ToArrayPar() function, wherever an Array is needed. This parallel version is about 3X faster than List.ToArray()